# regex for finding only between brackets

Tags: regex

Given the below regex and text-

```
regex - #\{.*\}
text - "abc #{:abc :cde} dont-mtach #{:xyz :wqt} do-not do-not-not")
```

I would like to get only `#{:abc :cde} #{:xyz :wqt}` in the result. However the above also gives me `dont-match` in the result. Any ideas how I should modify the regex ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#\{.*?\}
```

Make your `*` non greedy.Or simply use

```
#\{[^}]*\}
```

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/jG2wO4/4)

Comment: I am going to use the above for string interpolation. I want to capture any content which is in #{}. Do you forsee any instances where the above regex wont work ?

Comment: @murtaza52 it will work in all case except if there are more `{}` inside {}` like.`{asdas{asd}ASD}`

Comment: Thanks, that not a use case I am expecting, so it should work. An orthogonal question, I intend to use #{} the above for interpolating strings meant as shell commands. Do you forsee any conflicts with shell substitution syntax ? (I am not a shell programming expert thus confirming)

Comment: how will the regex change if I only want to extract from within the brackets. ie get everything inside #{} without the hash and brackets.

Comment: @murtaza52 you can use `#\{(.*?)\}` and grab `group 1 ` or if lookahead are supported `(?<=#\{).*?(?=\})`